# multiple if else conditions, promises in cypress

Tags: javascript, promise, cypress

I am new to cypress.I am trying to accomplish like a multiple if-else kind of situation, but not sure how to do it in cypress/javascript.
This is the scenario that I am trying to automate:

There are 4 months/buttons so say, June, July, August, Sep.
User clicks on June, and if there are no spots available in month of June then it shows "No results", then user clicks on July, if user again sees No results, then user should click on August.

This is what I have so far in cypress:

```
cy.get('.TabNavigation__Navigation-trsik5-1 > :nth-child(4)').click();
cy.wait(4000);
cy.get('body').then($body => {
    if ($body.text().includes('No results')) {
        //schedulingPage.clickToggleSecondMonthButton();
        cy.get('.TabNavigation__Navigation-trsik5-1 > :nth-child(2)').click();
    } else if ($body.text().includes('No results')) {
        // schedulingPage.clickToggleThirdMonthButton();
        cy.get('.TabNavigation__Navigation-trsik5-1 > :nth-child(3)').click();
    } else if ($body.text().includes('No results')) {
        //schedulingPage.clickToggleFourthMonthButton();
        cy.get('.TabNavigation__Navigation-trsik5-1 > :nth-child(1)').click();
    }
});
```

Obviously doesnt work all the way. 
Cypress clicks on `nth-child(4)`, when it sees "No results", it goes to `nth-child(2)`, it again sees "No results", now it doesnt know what to do.

How can I accomplish this?

So its like I click on Sep, if result is "No results," click on June, if result is "No results", click on July...

Comment: Your if condition doesn't make any sense. Each condition should be different. All of yours are the same. So the first one is true, it never reaches the 2nd or 3rd

Comment: you are right! okay let me see what I can do! thanks!